# How to ignore 'where' and 'order by' condition if the column is null in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have list of transaction objects and want to order them by certain condition depending on view user is currently on.

The problem I have is that in order to add a condition in a where clause, first I need to check if it is null or not to prevent null pointer exception. This causes records with the column null being filtered out(and I want to include them at bottom of the list).

How can I modify the query so that it ignores the conditions(where and order by) if that column is null and still append them to the result set?

This is one example query:

```
transactions = transactions
                    .Where(t => t.PurchaseRequisition != null && 
                    t.Award != null && t.PurchaseRequisition.RequisitionedBy != null)
                    .OrderBy(t => t.Award.ContractNumber).
                    ThenBy(t => ToSafeString(t.Award.ContractNumber)).
                    ThenBy(t => ToSafeString(t.PurchaseRequisition.RequisitionedBy.FullName));


public string ToSafeString(string s)
{
    return s ?? String.Empty;
}
```

// I want records where PurchaseRequisition or Award is null to be appended to the result set.

Comment: How can you order only a part of resultset? I think you would need two queries then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to modify your `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` clauses:

```
.OrderBy(t => t.Award == null || t.Award.ContractNumber == null)
.ThenBy(t => t.Award == null ? "" : ToSafeString(t.Award.ContractNumber))
.ThenBy(t => t.PurchaseRequisition == null ? "" 
             : ToSafeString(t.PurchaseRequisition.RequisitionedBy.FullName));
```

Now you can completely remove the `Where` clause.

Comment: Can you explain how that OrderBy parameter will work? What the generated SQL might look like? I've never seen it used that way.

Comment: It seems to be working, can you explain what the first order by condition do? By the way you did it, it looks like it will place records with null columns at the top.

Comment: @SteveMallory: I am not sure how the SQL will look like, you just would have to check it.

Comment: @joonho: The first `OrderBy` simply treats an `Award` that is `null` the same as a `ContractNumber` that is null. If you want the `null`s at the end, use `OrderByDescending` instead.