# combine two list and linq query to order by two different fields from different lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have lists with different fields:

```
var list1 = // contains 'publish date'
var list2 = // contains 'press release date'
var list3 = // contains 'publish date'
var list4 = // contains 'press release date'
```

I need to combine these lists first and then order by the latest of publish date or press release date.

Tried per this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10109230/2039603), list is output but it does not sort by the dates as expected

```
var combinedList = list1.Concat(list2)     
                        .Concat(list3)
                        .Concat(list4)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Fields["Press Release Date"] != null || x.Fields["Publish Date"] != null)
                        .ThenBy(x => x.Fields["Press Release Date"] != null ? x.Fields["Press Release Date"].ToString() : "")
                        .ThenBy(x => x.Fields["Publish Date"] != null ? x.Fields["Publish Date"].ToString() : "").ToList();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Will be much easier if you show the types of those 4 lists

Comment: All lists are of same type - Sitecore.Data.Items.Item

Comment: what do you mean doesn't sort by dates as expected? what is the input and what do you get at the end?

Comment: so you use `OrderByDescending` do you know we also have `ThenByDescending`? maybe that's your problem

Comment: @GiladGreen:  Not sorted by descending order of dates. Input is unsorted list of items,  I get the output as concatenated list of items but not sorted by descending dates.

Comment: `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Fields["Press Release Date"] != null || x.Fields["Publish Date"] != null)` this part just doesn't make sense. you want to order by bool value? I suggest you use `Where` to separate null values from other values. sort your list and finally merge two lists.

Answer (score 0):

This code was not tested since you did not give an example of the lists, but you can try it:

```
var combinedList = OrderByDescending(x => x.Fields["Press Release Date"] != null ? x.Fields["Press Release Date"].ToString() : x.Fields["Publish Date"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Assumption about the lists:

each member has exactly one of the two fields - either "Press Release Date" or "Publish Date".